# Impossible to start ACTION_SEND activity in my activitiesManager / Strange behavior of onKeyUp event

Tags: android, email, android-activity, android-intent, onkeyup

In my android application, I use my own ActivityGroup (named TabGroupActivity) in order to manage several activities in a tabHost.

So, when I want start a activity, I use the following method of TabGroupActivity :

```
public void startChildActivity(String Id, Intent intent) {
      Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(Id,intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
      if (window != null) 
      {
          mIdList.add(Id);
          setContentView(window.getDecorView());
      }    
  }
```

The problem is when I try to start a ACTION_SEND intent with this method. I have the following error :

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Requesting code from com.android.mms to be run in process com.myProject
```

Someone can tell me if it's possible to start a activity like "ACTION_SEND" with this method ? The problem seems to come from the  "getLocalActivityManager.startActivities" ?

For now, to avoid this error, I call startActivity without use TabGroupActivity.startChildActivity but I have a really strange behavior of the ACTION_SEND activity !!

I explain :
In TabGroupActivity the fonction onKeyUp is override so I put a Log when I enter in this fonction.
And when I use the back button in order to quit the mail_activity my Log is printed half the time!! totally random !! I don't understand why !

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

For java.lang.SecurityException : you need to add the permission in the AndroidManifest file. since you are trying to do something with Messaging application(com.android.mms).